# iOS - Possible to create a ARKit app to count number of same objects?

Tags: ios, image, arkit

I had tried several ARKit examples to detect images and I want to create an app to counter number of mahjong tiles in a scene. But I found that (and googled for a while) seems no way to detect same tile in a scene? My demo app can only detect first occurrence but there are 4 identical tile in a mahjong.

Is it any way to solve this issue? thanks!

Comment: no and I pause the project, will check this again after next WWDC....

Comment: I achieved this using ML Kit.